# Flash is unavailable - Electron app (Chromium browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, flash, electron, chromium

I am trying to play Flash content in my electron app (Chromium browser). For that I have added pepflashplayer.dll in my project parallel to index.js and added below code suggested everywhere -

```
var app = require('app');
// Added browser-window, path as well...

if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    ppapi_flash_path = path.join(__dirname, 'pepflashplayer.dll');
} else if (process.platform == 'linux') {
    ppapi_flash_path = path.join(__dirname, 'libpepflashplayer.so');
} else if (process.platform == 'darwin') {
    ppapi_flash_path = path.join(__dirname, 'PepperFlashPlayer.plugin');
}

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-path', ppapi_flash_path);
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-version', '24.0.0.221');


app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        // https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md
        'min-width': 1000,
        'min-height': 400,
        width: 1200,
        height: 600,
        center: true,
        resizable: true,
        webPreferences: {
            plugins: true
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadUrl(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
```

But whenever I am playing flash content, I am getting this error -

Flash is unavailable in your browser

I have tried with 64bit as well as 32bit DLLs. Tried to download DLLs form multiple sources and used the one available with Chrome browser as well but no luck.

Would really appreciate for any help. Thanks!

Comment: Flash is not included in Chromium builds. Better use Chrome to test your code if you really want to use flash

Comment: I know. But there has to be a way to include flash in Chromium. Chromium is obvious choice to be bundled with electron app and its not about just testing, I will be distributing my app. Can not use chrome.

Comment: AFAIK, flash is NPAPI plugin. Here's how to work with NPAPI plugins: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/npapi Remember, NPAPI will be soon be phased out so this technique might not work in the future